# Protection stack overflow with the C interface for R

Tags: r, c, stack-overflow

I'm currently writing a R package for Delaunay and Voronoï tessellations in 3D. Most of the implementation is done in C (with the help of the Qhull library).

While running the Delaunay triangulation on a large number of points (> 10000), I received this error:

> Error: protect(): protection stack overflow

In my C code, I run `UNPROTECT` at the end of the functions, only one time. I'm wondering: if I split the code in blocks, to run `UNPROTECT` multiple times instead of one time (e.g. each time I reach 1000 `PROTECT`), could it change something? Is there a known limit for the number of protections?

Comment: In general it is advisable to run `UNPROTECT` every time you exit a function that is exposed to R users, and even whenever exiting a function from within C that uses R's C types (SEXP). I believe the 10000 constant is defined in the source code to avoid memory overflow, but I would imagine it is vastly undervalued on modern computers. Maybe asking this to [R-package-devel](https://www.r-project.org/mail.html) would give a better yield. You could also convert all your types to C types, and only write the final results to an SEXP avoiding PROTECT all together.

Comment: Your spelling of “Voronoï” has made me realise that I have always mispronounced this name (along with Delaunay’s).

Answer (score 0):

I finally removed the `PROTECT`s in the `for` loops:

```c
  PROTECT(R_vertices = allocVector(VECSXP, nsites));
  PROTECT(vnames = allocVector(STRSXP, nsites));
  nprotect += 2;
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < nsites; i++) {
    SEXP vertex = SiteSXP(vertices[i], dim);
    //    SEXP vertex;
    //    PROTECT(vertex = SiteSXP(vertices[i], dim));
    //    nprotect++;
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(R_vertices, i, vertex);
    SET_STRING_ELT(vnames, i, Rf_asChar(VECTOR_ELT(vertex, 0)));
  }
  setAttrib(R_vertices, R_NamesSymbol, vnames);
```

It seems they are not necessary. I don't output the `vertex`s at the end, I only store them in `R_vertices`.